# The expected value of a random variable raised to a power of more than two

Tags: probability, expected-value

I have come across a question that asks me to find $E((1+X)^3)$. The only values given in the question are $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$ and I tried to solve it by expanding $(1+X)^3$. But with this approach, I have an $E(X^3)$ term that I don't know how the find the value of. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: The values of $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$ are 1 and 4 respectively.

Comment: What are $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$?

Comment: Do you know anything else about $X$?

Comment: You  cannot find $EX^{3}$ and $E(1+X)^{3}$ from the given data. May be you are not quoting the question you came across properly.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy No these are the only information given in the question and I've quoted them correctly

Comment: Is anything known about the distribution of $X$? If there is no further info then the question cannot be answered. Random variables $X_1,X_2$ can be constructed with $\mathbb EX_1=1=\mathbb EX_2$ and $\mathbb EX_1^2=4=\mathbb EX_2^2$ and $\mathbb E(1+X_1)^3\neq\mathbb E(1+X_2)^3$.

Comment: See also this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3191938/how-to-determine-ex3-given-ex2-and-ex
In that question $E(X)^2 = E(X^2)$ such that $X$ was constant and $E(X^3) = E(X)^3$. Maybe you misread the question